# How do I do indexOf for arrays with optionals?

Tags: arrays, indexof, swift2

In Swift2, how can you do `indexOf` on arrays that contain optionals? The following example won't compile:

```
var strings: [String?] = ["hello", nil, "world"]
let index = strings.indexOf("world")
```

with the compiler complaining

*"Cannot invoke indexOf with an argument list of type '(String)'"*

A naive approach without `indexOf` would be:

```
let index: Int = {
    for var i = 0; i < strings.count; i++ {
        let s: String? = strings[i]
        if s == "world" {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}()
```

Isn't there any way to use the built-in `indexOf` function?

The same example however works for arrays with non-optionals:

```
var strings: [String] = ["hello", "world"]
let index = str.indexOf("world")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or even simpler:

```
let strings: [String?] = ["hello", nil, "world"]
strings.indexOf{ $0 == "world" }
```

This works because `==` is defined for optionals as well

Comment: Nice tip. I'm leaving my answer as it is because yours complement it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression in "trailing closure" for `indexOf`:

```
var arr: [String?] = ["hello", nil, "world"]
let i = arr.indexOf() { $0 != nil && $0 == "world" }
```